# jQuery checkbox check-uncheck issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkboxes on my page:

```
<div class="mail-control">
    <input class="magic-checkbox select-doc" type="checkbox">
    <label for="email-list-1"></label>
</div>
```

I also have links to select and deselect all checkboxes:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="select-all-list">Select all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="deselect-all-list">Deselect all</a></li>
</ul>
```

This code selects and deselects the checkboxes:

```
$('#select-all-list').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-doc').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#deselect-all-list').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-doc').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**The problem is: when I select all checkboxes - I can't uncheck some of them manually (directly with my mouse). How do I do it?**

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: @SmitRaval You answer is, in fact, correct, but it should be voted to close as a "type error" problem.

Comment: @SmitRaval -- Do not poke the OP to check your answer. If they find your answer useful, they will accept/upvote it.

Comment: @freedomn-m Correct, Long night :p Thanks

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now, select all and deselect all are working properly, but still I can't uncheck some of the checked checkboxes. If I try to uncheck some checkbox - it affects only first checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing `false` property in `deselect-all-list` click event:

```js
$('#select-all-list').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-doc').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#deselect-all-list').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-doc').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mail-control">
    <input class="magic-checkbox select-doc" type="checkbox">
    <label for="email-list-1"></label>
    <input class="magic-checkbox select-doc" type="checkbox">
    <label for="email-list-1"></label>
    <input class="magic-checkbox select-doc" type="checkbox">
    <label for="email-list-1"></label>
</div>


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="select-all-list">Select all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="deselect-all-list">Deselect all</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('#deselect-all-list').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-doc').prop('checked', true);
});
```

to this

```
$('#deselect-all-list').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-doc').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now, select all and deselect all are working properly, but  still I can't uncheck some of the checked checkboxes. If I try to uncheck some checkbox - it affects only first checkbox.

Comment: Its a same ID problem. You have given same id in label for and checkboxes. Give unique id to checkboxes and in label for. Your problem will get resolved. Also if this answer solved your primary issue please mark as accepted. Thanks. :) @HugeD